# More specific Type from base shared constructor

Tags: vb.net, reflection, shared

How do I get using reflection the most generic type from a shared constructor in the base class :

```
Public Class Foo()
   Shared Sub New()
       'Here we have code to get the type!
        MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
   End
End Class

Public Class Bar()
  Inherits Foo

End Class
```

I expect the result to be `Bar` type and not the `Foo`. Is it possible?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What about types inheriting your class in another assembly that you don't know about? What if there are multiple types at the same inheritance level? How deep down the tree do you want to go?

Comment: Yon want the most *specific* type, not generic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it seems you want to find the most *derived* type (or the most *specific* type), not the most generic type -- which would mean rather the opposite (either, that generics are involved, or that the most *general* type is being sought).

While it may be possible to do this using reflection, your need for it might indicate that you have your class design wrong, or less than optimal.

First, constructors aren't virtual methods, so inside a constructor (IIRC), the `Me` object reference is of the type that contains this constructor.

What you could do is reflect over all of an assembly's types and find all those that are derived from `Foo`. You would then have to build a inheritance graph of these types and assign a number to each saying how far it is derived from `Foo` (number of inheritance levels). You could then check the `Me` object reference against all of the types you've identified (see if `Me` can be cast to each of them), and from that subset, choose the one type with the largest number of inheritance levels.

I hope that from this, you'll see that it's probably not worth the effort. It would be more interesting, and probably more helpful, to re-think why you need to do this, and if possible, find a way to avoid it.